# Python - Postgres query using sqlalchemy returns "Empty Dataframe"

Tags: python, database, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I try to query some data from a postgres database and add the results into an excel with the below Python code (I am connecting to the server through ssh tunnel and connecting to database using sqlalchemy):

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('<server_ip>', 22),
    ssh_username="<server_username>",
    ssh_private_key='<private_key_path>', 
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432)) as server:
    server.start()
    print "server connected"

    #connect to DB
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://<db_username>:<db_password>:' + local_port +'/<db_name>')
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    print 'Database session created'

    not_empty_query = False #flag empty queries
    arg_query = "SELECT * from portalpage where id not in (select entityid from sharepermissions where entitytype='PortalPage')"
    query = s.execute(arg_query)
    print(query)
    for row in query: #check if the query is empty
        if (row[0] > 0):
            not_empty_query = True
            break
    if not_empty_query == True: #if the query isn not empty add response into excel
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 8)))
        df = DataFrame(query.fetchall())
        print(df)
        df.columns = query.keys()
        df.to_excel("out.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", sheet_name="Worksheet_Name")

s.close()
```

It works for the most of the queries that I tried to execute, however with the above query it returns the below error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 8 elements
```

While I was troubleshooting I printed the the df parameter and I got an "Empty Dataframe".
However when I run the same query in my database directly I get results.

I also noticed that in the response, on my database, some columns are empty (not sure if it makes any difference).

Please also find a print screen of the code execution.
[image]

The above will work if I remove the below piece of code:

```
for row in query: #check if the query is empty
    if (row[0] > 0):
        not_empty_query = True
        break
if not_empty_query == True:
```

However, if I remove this 'for loop' then for other queries (mainly for queries which return empty results) I get the same error.
Please find an example below.
[image]

Ay ideas?

Comment: use @Spyros_av idea. get all the data into the dataframe first and then push to excel

Comment: As I replied below even if I define an empty dataframe I still get the same error.

Comment: can you share the updated script? so we can see why it doesn't work

Comment: I want to be sure that you used `pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 8))) ` to create an empty dataframe to house the query results. this is what @Spyros_av suggested.

Comment: Note that you can use `query.keys()` to create the empty dataframe to make it dyanamic.

Comment: I edited the code above and added what @Spyros_av suggested. But I get the same error.

Comment: Hi @MEdwin, I am already using the query.keys() to dynamically set the columns.

Comment: Are you sure you get the same error message? I just tried your code with SQLite and it works. Please see if the error message is different.

Comment: @MEdwin I just added a screenshot of my code execution. Please have a look and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: remove this part from your script `for row in query: #check if the query is empty
        if (row[0] > 0):
            not_empty_query = True
            break`

Comment: Once you call `query`, it pulls all the values and becomes blank. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi @MEdwin, you were correct, that worked for the initial query that I had. However I have added this for clause as I was getting the same errors when i run a query which was empty. I edited the post and I added a better explanation. Can you please have a look and share your thoughts with me?

Comment: Also to be more specific, the for loop was the problem and if I remove it, the one query works even if I don't add the `pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 8)))` part. But still the empty queries keep returning the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I found that the logic you are using to check if the query returns any data is the problem. I have  modified it to have that check first. If there is any row returned then it builds the dataframe and then exports to excel. Please let me know if it works.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('<server_ip>', 22),
    ssh_username="<server_username>",
    ssh_private_key='<private_key_path>', 
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432)) as server:
    server.start()
    print "server connected"

    #connect to DB
    local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://<db_username>:<db_password>:' + local_port +'/<db_name>')
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    s = Session()
    print 'Database session created'
    arg_query = "SELECT * from portalpage where id not in (select entityid from sharepermissions where entitytype='PortalPage')"
    query = conn.execute(arg_query)##rows_count
    rows = query.fetchall()
    columns=query.keys()
    if len(rows) > 0:
        df = DataFrame(rows)
        df.columns =columns
        df.to_excel("out.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", sheet_name="Worksheet_Name")
    else:
        print "no data"
```

Comment: I get the same error, also I noticed that it goes into the if clause even if the query doesn't return any results and if I print the query variable before the if clause it returns this: `<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x1207a2a90>`

Comment: I think I found what it is. I have modified the script: the `query.fetchall()` and `query.keys()` needs to store their values before the loop. Please check again.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be working perfectly. Thank you @MEdwin.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an empty data frame first.

```
if not_empty_query == True: #if the query isn not empty add response into excel
        df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.empty((0, 8)))   
        df = DataFrame(query.fetchall())
        print(df)
        df.columns = query.keys()
        df.to_excel("out.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", sheet_name="Worksheet_Name")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I still get the same error. Also ideally I want to have a dynamic size for my dataframe as I will use it in a function and I will run multiple queries.